# Setting up rows inside a 2 column layout with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to setup 2 columns, one "col-9" and the other "col-3", but I'd like to treat the inside of each as it's own "col-12" grid. Something similar to:

[Grids inside 2 Columns Layout visual](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1MiFsC4Dnv-xexAhS2Z2u3btXos-VMMTrMjdlOgSW764/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried with this:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 left-side">
                            {{i}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3]">
                    <div class="right-side">
                        {{i}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've put together this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toddrun/v27hdysw/), but as you can see, I can't seem to solve the placement of the right hand column.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you closed the `row` tag and opened a new one when you shouldn't have. See this:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 left-side">
                            {{i}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Removed From Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3]">
                    <div class="right-side">
                        {{i}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I removed a pair of `</div>` and `<div class="row">` right before `<div class="col-xs-3">`. That way, the second column won't appear below the first, but beside it instead. See the updated JSFiddle for clarification.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v27hdysw/1/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! I updated my fiddle, though kept the error so others can see my error.